# Extract data from sql using python, do transformations and write back to sql table

Tags: python, sql

I have a scenario where I need to extract data from different sql tables, use that data to transform it in python and next I need to write back the result to a SQL table.

1. Is this possible?
2. Is it an efficient way? Or would you recommend using different tools?
3. How can I automate the python script to run it automatically from a server?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Of course it's possible.
2. I think it depends on what kind of transformations you want to apply and your knowledge on python and SQL. I mean if the transformation is something like replacing and simple math functions you can do this using SQL codes but in case of complex functions and maybe lack of SQL code knowledge you should use python. And I suggest using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).
3. You can simply run it in shell and use cron-job if you need to run it on specific schedule.

Comment: I am a junior data engineer that just started working in the field. I am proficient in SQL and Python but still need to learn which to use and when. If I need to pull the data from SQL what library would you use? Sqlalchemy or pyodbc?

Comment: I have experience in performing jobs on both python and SQL. In my opinion in two cases you should use SQL: (1) if your task is simple (doable in SQL) and its a one time task or (2) if your task is simple (doable in SQL) and you need to store or change data directly in SQL database. But other than that performing analyze and change on data in python is simpler and the community and tools are great and in many cases the performance is not so different from SQL.

Comment: As a data engineer you should consider the time you (or your team) will spend on the task (and the time you will need to upgrade or change function) and then put it on a plate with the performance you need from the function and then decide which one is more important to you.For example a while a go I needed a function to work with timestamp in a different calendar. At first I wrote a function is SQL to do simple jobs but later when the functions got more complex and other calendars came in the picture I was forced to use python.

Comment: Clear answer, many thanks. But how would you pull the data out of a SQL database using python? sqlalchemy or pyodbc?

Comment: And the last advice: Always keep in mind that in the future you may need to upgrade the code or somebody else might become the manager of that code. Basically codes in python are more readable and easier to understand and debug and the also know that there are not lots of developers that can code in SQL (specially in complex cases) but because of the features in python you can find suitable python developers easier.

Comment: Regarding pulling data out of SQL: You can use both of them but I recommend to use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html). It will take more time to understand basics of Pandas but it will worth it since it's so powerful and in the future you can almost do any thing with your data.